# Threaded gRPC client app causes segmentation fault on multiple stream clients

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, grpc

I have a simple gRPC service implementation as follows:

```
service TestService {
  rpc stringService(Empty) returns (stream StringTest) {}
  rpc intService(Empty) returns (stream IntTest) {}
}

message StringTest {
  string my_string = 1;
}

message IntTest {
  int32 my_int= 1;
}

message Empty {}
```

The idea is simply just to continuously stream integers and strings to a client. The server implementation is as follows:

```
class TestServiceImpl final: public TestService::Service {
public:

grpc::Status TestServiceImpl::stringService(grpc::ServerContext *context, const Empty *request, ::grpc::ServerWriter<StringTest> *writer) override
{
    StringTest data;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
        data.set_my_string(std::to_string(i));
        sleep(1);
        writer->Write(data);
        if (i == 10) i = 0;
    }

    return grpc::Status::OK;
}

grpc::Status TestServiceImpl::intService(grpc::ServerContext *context, const Empty *request, ::grpc::ServerWriter<IntTest> *writer) override
{
    IntTest data;
    for (int i = 10; i <= 20; ++i) {
        data.set_my_int(i);
        sleep(1);
        writer->Write(data);
        if (i == 20) i = 10;
    }

    return grpc::Status::OK;
}
};

int main() {
    std::string addr("127.0.0.1:50051");
    TestServiceImpl service;
    grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
    builder.AddListeningPort(addr, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << addr << std::endl;
    server->Wait();
    return 0;
}
```

And for the client side, I have `StringClient` and `IntClient` classes to connect to the server streams and handle the data received. They are implemented as dynamically loaded libraries and derived from an `AbstractClient` class to provide a common interface (note that only the `start()` function is relevant here).

AbstractClient.h:

```
class AbstractClient : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    virtual ~AbstractClient() { }
    AbstractClient(QObject *parent): QObject(parent) {}

    virtual void send(::google::protobuf::Message *msg) {}
    virtual void recv() = 0;
    virtual void start() {}
    virtual void stop() {}

signals:
    void messageReceived(QString);
};

#define AbstractClient_iid "test.AbstractClient"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(AbstractClient, AbstractClient_iid)
```

I have a GRPCThread class which is intended to be subclassed for each gRPC stream:

```
class GRPCThread: public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GRPCThread(QObject *parent=nullptr): QThread(parent) {}
    ~GRPCThread() {}

protected:
    std::unique_ptr<TestService::Stub> m_stub;
};
```

And my client plugin classes with the thread implementations:
StringClient.h:

```
class StringClient : public AbstractClient
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "test.str")
    Q_INTERFACES(AbstractClient)

public:
    explicit StringClient(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~StringClient() {}

    void recv() override {}
    void start() override;

private:
    QPointer<StringThread> m_stringThread;

class StringThread: public GRPCThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void run() override;
};
```

StringClient.cpp:

```
StringClient::StringClient(QObject *parent): AbstractClient(parent) {
    m_stringThread = new StringThread();
}

void StringClient::start() {
    m_stringThread->start();
}

void StringThread::run()
{
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("127.0.0.1:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
    ::grpc::ClientContext context;
    ::Empty request;
    m_stub = TestService::NewStub(channel);
    auto reader = m_stub->stringService(&context, request); // Seems to segfault here

    StringTest stringMsg;
    while (reader->Read(&stringMsg)) {
        std::cout << stringMsg.my_string() << std::endl;
    }

    auto status = reader->Finish();
}
```

And similarly, IntClient.h:

```
class IntClient : public AbstractClient
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "test.int")
    Q_INTERFACES(AbstractClient)

public:
    explicit IntClient(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~IntClient() {}

    void recv() override {}
    void start() override;

private:
    QPointer<IntThread> m_IntThread;
};

class IntThread : public GRPCThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void run() override;
};
```

IntClient.cpp:

```
IntClient::IntClient(QObject *parent): AbstractClient(parent)
{
    m_IntThread = new IntThread();
}

void IntClient::start()
{
    m_IntThread->start();
}

void IntThread::run()
{
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("127.0.0.1:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());

    ::grpc::ClientContext context;
    ::Empty request;

    m_stub = TestService::NewStub(channel);
    auto reader = m_stub->intService(&context, request); // Seems to segfault here

    IntTest IntMsg;
    while (reader->Read(&IntMsg)) {
        std::cout << IntMsg.my_int() << std::endl;
    }

    auto status = reader->Finish();
}
```

And then, I compile the `StreamClient` and `IntClient` classes to .so libraries, no problem with that. Then I have a client application which has to load them using QPluginLoader:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    AbstractClient *abs = nullptr;

    QPluginLoader loader("/path/to/libStringClient.so");
    loader.load();
    abs = qobject_cast<AbstractClient*>(loader.instance());
    abs->start();

    loader.setFileName("/path/to/libIntClient.so");
    loader.load();
    abs = qobject_cast<AbstractClient*>(loader.instance());
    abs->start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

If I load just one plugin, it works flawlessly and starts receiving and outputting strings/int from gRPC server stream. The problem is that when I load both of the plugins, there is always a segmentation fault at the service call. If I observe the server output, occasionally the other thread reaches the service function, but crashes immediately.

So the problem is the segmentation fault. I have no idea what would cause it. It probably has something to do with thread safety, but I do not know what is the critical resource that should be access protected. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything that you read and write to at the same time needs to be protected by a mutex or by some other means. I'm not going to sit here and go through your 200+ lines of code. Please make your own debug efforts and come back here with a [mre] if you can't figure out the root cause.

Comment: Yeah this is kinda a minimum reproducible example, as the modular approach makes the solution spread across several classes/files, although the problem itself is rather simple. But I understand the concern.

Comment: It really isn't. It's minimum in the sense that you don't know what part of all this that is causing the problem. Finding that out is actually your job. Start removing and simplifying the code one step at a time. When the issue disapears you've removed too much. At a glance this could probably be reduced to 20 lines of code or less.

Comment: Taking into account that the problem appears specifically when the client code is loaded as Qt plugins who share the same plugin interface, it is not really so easy to describe the problem in less rows so that the whole system is described. Of course, I could simplify the question down to "the m_stub->xService() call crashes when I have more than one grpc client threads", but it wouldn't be very useful as that approach works very well when implemented directly in a minimal way without the whole plugin framework.